# Error: [$parse:syntax] and home.html 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angularjs

I began following a [tutorial](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails) to AngularJs today, but implementing something slightly different, now I'm stuck, seems that Angular is not recognizing the inline template "home".

P.S: To run this locally on chrome I had to install a webserver.

```js
angular.module('little_tweet', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $stateProvider
 .state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: '/home.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl'
 })
 .state('posts', {
   url: '/posts/{id}',
   templateUrl: '/posts.html',
   controller: 'PostsCtrl'
 });

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

}])
.factory('posts', [function() {
 var o = { posts: []};
 return o;
}])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts', function($scope, posts){
  $scope.posts = posts.posts;
  
  $scope.current_user = 'me';
   
   $scope.addPost = function() {
    if(!$scope.message || $scope.message === '') { return; }
    
    $scope.posts.push({
     user: $scope.current_user,
     message: $scope.message, 
     time: new Date()
    });

  $scope.message = '';
 };
}])
.controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'posts', function($scope, $stateParams, posts) {
 $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
}]);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Little Tweet</title>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="little_tweet">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   
   <ui-view></ui-view>
      
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Little Tweet</h1>
      </div>

      <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
          {{{post.user}}: {{post.message}} at {{post.time}}
        </span>
      </div>

      <form ng-submit="addPost()"
        style="margin-top:30px;">
        <h3>Add a new post</h3>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Message"
            ng-model="message"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
   <div class="page-header">
     <h1>Little tweet</h1>
   </div>

   <!-- rest of template -->
 </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `/` from template url in routes.

***EDIT***
there is an extra `{` in `{{{post.user}}: {{post.message}} at {{post.time}}`.

Comment: Additional explanation for why this works would improve your answer.

Comment: templateUrl: '/home.html',
Now it's
templateUrl: 'home.html',

And still it gives me the same error, I also tried to change
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="\home.html">
to
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">

Comment: Now it doesn't give me errors, but also doesn't add the posts when submitted, any clues?